# GeoJson To TopoJSon Conversion

Tags: python, npm

I am trying to convert Shapefile to Topojson. currently i am using npm version 2.15.11.

I am using the following steps:

1.Shapefile to GeoJson:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:4326 geo_json.json geo_shape.shp
```

2.Geojson to Topojson:

```
geo2topo -o geo_topo.json levels=geo_json.json
```

This command is running successfully but in `'transform'` object is not creating inside the topojson file. So i can't load topojson inside map.

Please help me if i am using any wrong commands.

Answer (score 1):

Using npm (vers 3.10.10), I installed topojson using `npm install topojson`
I usually use QGIS to convert a shapefile to a geojson file. But ogr2ogr should work.
To convert GeoJSON to TopoJSON, I run the following command (using topojson vers 3.0.2)
`geo2topo path_to_geojson_file > path_to_topojson_file`